# Entity Framework - deleting N:N relation

Tags: entity-framework, entity-framework-4

I have the following class

```
public class ObjectA{
   private List<ObjectB> list;    
}
```

`ObjectA` and `ObjectB` are in N:N relation.

I want to delete only the relation and I use

```
 while (objectA.list.Any())
        objectA.list.Remove(objectA.list.First());
```

- List is of the relation table -

  ```
  List<ObjectAobjectB>
  ```

And I get

> *The operation failed: The relationship could not be changed because one or more of
>   the foreign-key properties is non-nullable. When a change is made to a relationship, 
>   the related foreign-key property is set to a null value. If the foreign-key does not 
>   support null values, a new relationship must be defined, the foreign-key property 
>   must be assigned another non-null value, or the unrelated object must be deleted.*

**EDIT:** updating model definition
There are three tables in my model :
 * ClassA         - SchemaA,
 * ClassAClassB   - SchemaA,
 * ClassB         - SchemaB,

In my contex (and edmx ) I have only Schema A ( ClassA and ClassAClassB)
There for it is 1:N to the relation Table.

Here is the code generated from the edmx.

```
public partial class ClassA:DomainEntity
{
    ....
    public virtual ICollection<ClassB>  ClassAClassB { get; set; }
}
```

What am I doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Looks like something is wrong with your mapping because EF believes that the relation is 1:N. How is your ObjectB defined?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka : No ClassB in the edmx at all. Added definition. Thanks,

Comment: If you have ClassAClassB in schema you don't have M:N relation mapped. You instead have two 1:N relations and your ClassA and ClassB must have navigation properties pointed to ClassAClassB. Why do you have ClassAClassB mapped? Does it contain anything else except FKs?

Comment: @LadislavMrnka : Thanks for your comment. Well basically every M:N relation in the DB consists of two 1:N relation and relation table betweeen. I dont have ClassB cause I dont need it (And it is in another Schema). I need to delete only the relation. I do have navigation proerty (1:N) from ClassA to ClassAClassB.

Answer (score 1):

If you have one-to-many relation with non-nullable FK you must also delete ObjectB because removing it from navigation property will only remove the relation (makes FK null) but does not remove the ObjectB itself. Try this:

```
 while (objectA.list.Any()) {
     var b = b;
     objectA.list.Remove(b);
     entities.DeleteObject(b);    
 }
```

Comment: Thanks. But I want to delete only the relation

Comment: In such case the ClassAClassB must have nullable FK.

Comment: Why ? 
I am removing the whole row in the relation table. Not only the key column

Comment: Yes and if you are removing row in mapped table (ClassAClassB) you must to delete it. EF will handle deletion automatically only if the junction table is not mapped as entity.